# Google Sign out not working properly using react

Tags: reactjs, authentication, google-api

I am trying to implement Google API integration to signin and out of the application. I am using react library **react-google-login** for it

`<GoogleLogin>` is working fine . But when i tried to logout it just setting the state out. From the below code one can understand that

```
<GoogleLogout
          buttonText="Logout"
          onLogoutSuccess={(response) => { this.setState(() => { return { isSignedIn: false } }) }}
        ></GoogleLogout>
```

Instead i want to logout the user completely from google itself.

Answer (score 1):

From your code and the document of react-google-login, maybe you miss some required props? You should provide three required props to `<GoogleLogout>`: `clientId`, `onLogoutSuccess` and `onFailure`. There is the source: https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login#logout-props

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and as a work around ,so then I installed gapi-script and added a button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onClick={this.logout}>
  Logout
</button>
```

And on click I do this:

```
logout (response) {
this.setState(state => ({
  isLogined: false,
  accessToken: ''
}));

  
const auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

if (auth2 != null) {
    auth2.signOut().then(
         auth2.disconnect().then(console.log('LOGOUT SUCCESSFUL'))
     )
   }  
}
```

Comment: How did you use gapi? I had to use window.gapi since it's an external script. I also couldnt get the hook to work and this is the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: I installed this https://www.npmjs.com/package/gapi-script